# Virtualbox system is not working like real system

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-nt-4

We have a system that is based on windows NT4, because of hardware limitation we are moving to linux on new hardware + virtual windows nt4 (virtualbox).

but the virtual one is not working as it have to,

Also i tried linux dd to copy real nt harddrive to virtual hard drive,but the system is not working as it have to .

more about the situation:

our external hardware is a n-port to map external com ports over tcp/ip.
the virtual pc boots with no problem,windows starts with no problem,application starts with no problem,communication just starts with no problem,but disconnect!with some timeout like errors.

**note: a fresh install of NT and softwares on VirtualBox also have the same problem.**

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple copies of the NT4 system running (physical and virtual at the same time), the connection issues may be due to the duplicate MAC addresses.

For an easier way to migrate your NT4 system to a virtual environment, you can use [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) then [convert the VMware image to a VirtualBox image](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-convert-vmware-image-to-virtualbox-image.html).

Comment: no, just 1 instance, also ping with external nport have no problem

Comment: What are your network settings for Virtual PC?

Comment: bridge ,ping and port mapping with nport have no problem

Comment: Does the VMware Converter does anything special?

Comment: It will get your physical environment copied & prepped for a virtual environment. dd will just copy it. Not sure on **all** of the modifications it makes.

Comment: could you provide a link for more information on what exactly VMware converter does that dd doesnot,and what kind of modification on OS you mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the system hosting the machine might be causing those problems?
I can imagine that if the Linux host does something to the COM ports that the virtual machine is using, you might get problems.

Since you're also using the VM on new hardware, can you verify that it is working correctly?

Comment: result was about test on a laptop,
also com ports does not exist physically on linux system, those are mapped directly in winnt on tcp ports with ip-address of external nport,